# Pentaho CDE doesnt load with console error

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-cde, pentaho-ctools

I've been having trouble getting CDE to load CDE filed in edit since a restart of the service earlier today.  We have similar issues another environment but haven't ever been able to get to the bottom the the issue.  When I edit a CDE file the page doesn't ever load properly and a error is displayed in the console, preview also doesn't work.  I've tried restarting the service again, & clearing my cache.  Opening CDA files still works fine and the app is up,I can also open the CDE files, just edit doesn't load properly.

> Error is on Pentaho user console 8.1.0.0.365:
>   Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getPropertyObject' of undefined

[image]

Comment: Which version you are using?

Answer (score 0):

Finally traced the issue to a .KTR file with an invalid name in our endpoints folder.  Once deleted and the service restarted the issue is resolved and the editor loads as usual.

We managed to track this down via an error buried in the console:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R6f9O.png)